# In a basketball championship $n$ teams participated. Knowing that $(n-4)$ teams played $5n$ matches, find $n$ (using geometry).

Tags: geometry

For reference:
This is an interesting exercise. It's in the geometry section of a book (polygons), I couldn't find a solution.

> In a basketball championship $n$ teams participated. Knowing that $(n-4)$ teams played $5n$ matches, find $n$. (Answer: $12$)

My progress:
I thought that the teams form a closed polygon and that maybe the games could be related to some property of the diagonals but I couldn't develop the exercise.

Comment: Did you abbreviate the conditions? I cannot seem to make sense of it. There are $n$ participating teams, $(n - 4)$ of whom played. What did the other four do? If they did not play, then it seems a stretch to say they participated. Did every team play against all of the others? How many times? Did all teams play the same number of matches?

Comment: @Pope  it's exactly like in the book...
$(n-4)$ players played $5n$ matches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the given condition it is clear that $n>4.$
Also, the number of matches is the same for each team.

Assume that each team is a vertex of a polygon with $n$ vertices. Each match is represented by a side or a diagonal of the polygon.
WLOG, associate randomly an index $i=1,2,\dots,n$ to each team.  Every team plays $n-1$ matches, but below I only count those that were not counted before.

$T_1$ plays $(n-1)$ matches
$T_2$ plays $(n-2)$ matches (the match with $T_1$ is already counted)
$\vdots$
$T_{n-4}$ plays $(n-(n-4)$) matches besides those played with $T_1,\dots,T_{n-3}.$

The total of the above matches is $$\begin{aligned}5n&= (n-1)+\dots+(n-(n-4))\\&=n(n-4)-\frac{(n-4)(n-3)}{2}\\&=\frac{(n-4)(n+3)}{2}\end{aligned}$$
solving the equivalent quadratic equation $$n^2-11n-12=0$$  gives $n=12$ or $n=-1,$ but the negative value does not satisfy the context.

There are $12$ teams in the championship.

Comment: +1. This appears to be the proper way of thinking about the problem (but it's not what comes to mind when I think of "championship"; after all, who wins?). That being so, a slightly-more-straightforward approach is to note that total number of matches among $n$ teams (ie, the total number of diagonals-and-sides of an $n$-gon) is ${n\choose2}$. The matches played by some $n-4$ teams are what remain if we remove games played by the last four teams among themselves, ${4\choose2}$. Thus, $${n\choose2}-{4\choose2}=5n \quad\to\quad\frac12n(n-1)-6=5n\quad\to\quad (n+1)(n-12)=0\quad\to\quad n=12$$